# How to toggle active class of tabs in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, toggle, use-state, react-toggle

I made 2 buttons 'Login' and 'Register'. I wanna toggle the **active** class on these button if the user wanna login or register. Here is the code.

```
const [buttonStatus, setButtonStatus] = useState('');

const buttonStatusHandler = () =>{

if(buttonStatus === ''){
  setButtonStatus('active')
}

else{
  setButtonStatus('')
}

}
```

JSX

```
<div className='button_wrap'>
     <button className={buttonStatus} onClick={buttonStatusHandler}>Login</button>
     <button className={buttonStatus} onClick={buttonStatusHandler}>Register</button>      
</div>
```

Output Im trying

[image]

Active class would be the yellow button.

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing? The code seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle the state and use a class merger function to conditionally toggle the active class for the respective buttons.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-smoke-fn27d4?file=/src/App.js)

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [buttonStatus, setButtonStatus] = useState("login");

  return (
    <div className="button_wrap">
      <button
        className={cm(buttonStatus, buttonStatus === "login" && "active")}
        onClick={() => setButtonStatus("login")}
      >
        Login
      </button>
      <button
        className={cm(buttonStatus, buttonStatus === "register" && "active")}
        onClick={() => setButtonStatus("register")}
      >
        Register
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function cm(...args) {
  return args.filter((v) => v).join(" ");
}
```

**Explanation of the `cm` function**

The class merger function takes in any amount of arguments as an array `args`. After that it iterates while filtering the class names. Each class name is checked for truthyness and if it's not truthy it gets filtered. Therefore, you can pass conditional expressions as arguments and if the condition is `false`, the class name will be filtered. After that the filtered class array is joined with `" "` resulting in a valid html class attribute value.

Comment: Thanks it worked, although I'm still thinking about this cm function and what it's doing!

Comment: @Mohit see updated answer